# python program stops after wifi connection discontinuity

Tags: python, multithreading, upload, raspberry-pi, sensors

I started learning Python two months ago and I have written a code for a Raspberry pi project. My problem is that the program stucks after some hours of operation. I think that in all cases, it stopped after some wifi connection drops. But I don't understand why the whole program stops if there something wrong with the wifi connection. It stops uploading values and renew the lcd screen messages it prints (I removed this and other stuff from the code in order to be more easy to read.)

The code starts at the startup (sudo python /home/pi/test.py &) and contains two Threads:

The "Control" thread reads temperature and humidity by using an i2c bus and a sensor am2315 and according to a temperature threshold, controls a relay through GPIO.

The "Thingspeak" thread reads the temperature threshold from a 'Thingspeak' channel and then uploads the measurements from the previous thread to 'Thingspeak'.

I really don't know what to do and how to search for any solutions.
Any help will be much appreciated.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from time import sleep
import datetime
import urllib2
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import threading
import smbus
from tentacle_pi.AM2315 import AM2315
import smtplib
import contextlib

sleep(120)
# Lock
tLock = threading.Lock()
# Global variables
tem_global = 0; hum_global = 0
tem_hi = 35; relay = 21
# GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay, False)
sleep(1)

def Control():
        global temg, humg, tem_hi, relay
        # AM2315 setup
        am = AM2315(0x5c,"/dev/i2c-1")
        I2C_address = 0x70; I2C_bus_number = 1; i2c_channel_setup = 1
        bus = smbus.SMBus(I2C_bus_number)                
        bus.write_byte(I2C_address, i2c_channel_setup)
        sleep(1)

        while True:
                try:
                        tem_local, hum_local = am2315meas()
                except:
                        tem_local = -1; hum_local = -1

                tLock.acquire()
                tem_global = tem_local; hum_global = hum_local
                if tem_local < tem_hi:
                        GPIO.output(relay, True)
                else:
                        GPIO.output(relay, False)
                tLock.release()
                sleep(150)

def Thingspeak():
        global tem_global, hum_global, tem_hi
        myAPI = "..."
        channelID = "..."
        baseURL = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=%s' % myAPI
        while True:
                sleep(30)
                try:
                        # Reading value from thingspeak
                        tLock.acquire()
                        with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/%s/fields/1/last?" % channelID)) as f_read:
                                tem_hi = float(fread.read())
                        t.Lock.release()
                        sleep(30)
                        # Uploading values to thingspeak
                        tLock.acquire()
                        with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + "&field1=%s" % tem_global + "&field2=%s" % hum_global)) as f_upload:
                                pass
                        tLock.release()
                except:
                        with open('/home/pi/errors.txt', mode='a') as file:
                                file.write('Network error recorded at %s.\n' % datetime.datetime.now())
                        file.close()
                        sleep(60)
                        continue

def Main():
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=Thingspeak)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=Control)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main()
```

Comment: `file.close()` in the except: block is wrong, `file` is in the scope of the `with` statement and is closed automatically by that statement as well.

Comment: Thank you for this correction!

Comment: You should also consider using `with tLock:` instead of explicitly calling the `acquire()` and `release()` methods on it. If an exception is thrown in the I/O operations the lock be left in an acquired state, which will deadlock your program.

Comment: Thank you again! I think maybe this causes the problem. I will try it and leave feedback. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. As James K Polk indicated, there was an error after the tLock.acquire(), every time the internet connection went off, causing deadlock of the program. Below is a corrected part of the code for anyone would be interested.

```
def Control():
        global tem_global, hum_global, tem_hi, relay
        # AM2315 setup
        am = AM2315(0x5c,"/dev/i2c-1")
        I2C_address = 0x70; I2C_bus_number = 1; i2c_channel_setup = 1
        bus = smbus.SMBus(I2C_bus_number)                
        bus.write_byte(I2C_address, i2c_channel_setup)
        sleep(1)

        while True:
                try:
                        tem_local, hum_local = am2315meas()
                except:
                        tem_local = -1; hum_local = -1

                with tLock:
                        tem_global = tem_local; hum_global = hum_local
                        if tem_local < tem_hi:
                                GPIO.output(relay, True)
                        else:
                                GPIO.output(relay, False)
                sleep(150)

def Thingspeak():
        global tem_global, hum_global, tem_hi
        myAPI = "..."
        channelID = "..."
        baseURL = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=%s' % myAPI
        while True:
                sleep(30)
                try:
                        # Reading value from thingspeak
                        with tLock:
                                with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/%s/fields/1/last?" % channelID)) as f_read:
                                        tem_hi = float(fread.read())
                        sleep(30)
                        # Uploading values to thingspeak
                        with tLock:
                                with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(baseURL + "&field1=%s" % tem_global + "&field2=%s" % hum_global)) as f_upload:
                                        pass
                except:
                        with open('/home/pi/errors.txt', mode='a') as file:
                                file.write('Network error recorded at %s.\n' % datetime.datetime.now())
                        sleep(60)
                        continue
```